# assert that all lists in a list of lists are equal

Tags: python

I want to check if all lists in a list of lists are equal.

One example for which I succeeded is a lists of two lists `l2` for which

```
all([a == b for a, b in zip(*l2)])
```

correctly returns `True` if `l2 = [[1,2],[1,2]]` and `False`when `l2 = [[1,2],[1,666]]`.

I expected to be able to directly use this code in the case in which the list of lists `l` has more lists in it by using the same code, but it seems to not work.

For example, when

```
l=[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]
all([a == b for a, b in zip(*l)])
```

returns the following error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

I do not understand why this is the case as the result of `zip(*l)` looks like it should work:

```
list(zip(*l))
>> [(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method (and the other answers here) don't consider that if the lists' lengths vary, zip will shorten them to the length of the shortest:

```py
all(a == b for a,b in zip([1,2], [1,2,3]))
>>> True
```

Firstly note that it's not necessary to construct a list in `all` like `all([...])` as this adds an extra iteration after list creation, whereas as I've done above uses a generator which evaluates as it goes along.

If each list has hashable elements, I'd exploit `set` to calculate the distinct elements and check there's only 1:

```py
len(set(tuple(x) for x in l)) == 1
```

If the elements aren't hashable, but do have the equals method defined on them (unlike your examples, since `int` *is* hashable) I'd compare each list to the first, possibly using a generator if you want to avoid comparing the first to itself:

```py
li = iter(l)
first = next(li)
all(x == first for x in li)
```

This still makes use of python's built-in list equals method and won't do *more* comparisons than any `zip` methods in the case that all the lists *are* equal.

The only case where the above is inefficient is if you have a list of long lists, where most but not all are equal. In that case it's possible a zip method would be quicker:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

all(len(set(x)) == 1 for x in zip_longest(*l))
```

Here I used zip_longest for the case the list lengths are unequal. If you knw the lengths are equal you can use `zip`. By default it fills values with `None` from the shorter lists once they 'run out' in the iterator, so only use this if your lists have no legitimate `None`s! (In that case you can set `zip_longest(..., fillvalue="<something not in the lists>"`).

Equivalent for non-hashable list elements (with equals method):

```py
all(all(i == x[0] for i in x[1:]) for x in zip_longest(*l))
```

Comment: thanks! the solution exploiting `set` was the most suited to my case

Answer (score 4):

Using the observation a == b and a == c imply a == c. You should test the first list with the other lists.

```
def equalLists(lists):
  return not lists or all(lists[0] == b for b in lists[1:])
```

---

```
>>> equalLists([])
True
>>> equalLists([1,2],[1,2])
True
>>> equalLists([1,2],[1,2],[1,2])
True
>>> equalLists([1,2],[1,2],[1,3])
False
```

Comment: More than likely sufficient, worth noting that if efficiency is absolutely key, if you are comparing a list of very long lists that occasionally differ early on, this will be slower to evaluate to false than a zip method as it compares the full lists rather than 1 element at a time

Comment: For example, `[[1] * 10**6, [1] * 10**6, [2] * 10**6]`

Comment: You are right - the best solution is always depends on the use case.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a set of tuples and check the size is 1, otherwise they are not all the same:

```
len(set(tuple(elem) for elem in l)) == 1
```

This will work for a list of lists of any length. It will also be more efficient than linear time comparisons.

(You have to convert to a tuple first because a list is not hashable and a set requires its members to be hashable.)

Answer (score 0):

You have three item after `zip`  `(1,1,1)`

Use

```
l=[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]
all([a == b for a, b, c in zip(*l)])
```

or

```
l=[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]
all([a == b for a, b, *_ in zip(*l)])  
# OR all([a == b for a, b, _ in zip(*l)])
# OR all([i[0] == i[1] for i in zip(*l)])
```

Edit as per comment.
To test all sub elements are equal

```
all([len(set(i)) == 1 for i in zip(*l)])
```

Comment: All these solutions returns True when the 3rd list is different, am I missing something?

Comment: I thought the OP only wanted to test the first two elements in the tuple. if not you will need `all([len(set(i)) == 1 for i in zip(*l)])`

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]
all([a == b == c for a, b, c in zip(*l)])
```

You're telling zip() there's 2 values to unpack but zip has 3 lists to unpack.